# Match CDS upfront amount between Quantlib and Markit Converter model

Tags: quantlib, cds, isda

I'm trying to reconciliate the upfront amount between the Markit converter model  (https://cds.ihsmarkit.com/converter.jsp) and the result from the quantlib IsdaCdsEngine function.

the difference is very tight, however after some research on the web and trying to modify the code, I still can't match the amount. as you can see in the below print, the clean upfront amount is 344,110 - 25,000 = 319,110 EUR

[image]

with quantlib, I'm calculating 319,287 EUR, see the python code below

Just wonder if someone has encountered the same issue and can help me on that.

thanks in advance and Merry Christmas

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd

interactive = 'get_ipython' in globals()

trade_date = ql.Date(18,12,2023)
ql.Settings.instance().setEvaluationDate(trade_date)

ql.IborCoupon.createAtParCoupons()

dep_tenors = [1,3,6]
dep_quotes = [0.039009,0.038972,0.037575]
isdaRateHelpers = [ql.DepositRateHelper(dep_quotes[i],
                                        dep_tenors[i]*ql.Period(ql.Monthly),
                                        2,ql.WeekendsOnly(),
                                        ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                                        False,ql.Actual360())
                   for i in range(len(dep_tenors))]

swap_tenors = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
swap_quotes = [0.033231,
               0.026972,
               0.024380,
               0.023181,
               0.022662,
               0.022522]

isda_ibor = ql.IborIndex('IsdaIbor',3*ql.Period(ql.Monthly),2,
                         ql.EURCurrency(),ql.WeekendsOnly(),
                         ql.ModifiedFollowing,False,ql.Actual360())
isdaRateHelpers = isdaRateHelpers + [
    ql.SwapRateHelper(swap_quotes[i],swap_tenors[i]*ql.Period(ql.Annual),
                      ql.WeekendsOnly(),ql.Semiannual,ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                      ql.Thirty360(ql.Thirty360.BondBasis),isda_ibor)
    for i in range(len(swap_tenors))]


spot_date = ql.WeekendsOnly().advance(trade_date, 2 * ql.Period(ql.Daily))

swap_curve = ql.PiecewiseFlatForward(trade_date, isdaRateHelpers, ql.Actual365Fixed())
discountCurve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(swap_curve)

probabilityCurve = ql.RelinkableDefaultProbabilityTermStructureHandle()

termDate = ql.Date(20, 12, 2028)

spread = 0.003212
recovery = 0.4

upfront_date = ql.WeekendsOnly().advance(trade_date, 3 * ql.Period(ql.Daily))


cdsSchedule = ql.Schedule(trade_date, termDate,
                            3*ql.Period(ql.Monthly),
                            ql.WeekendsOnly(),
                            ql.Following, ql.Unadjusted,
                            ql.DateGeneration.CDS, False)

quotedTrade = ql.CreditDefaultSwap(
                ql.Protection.Buyer,10000000,0,spread,cdsSchedule,
                ql.Following,ql.Actual360(),True,True,trade_date,
                upfront_date, ql.FaceValueClaim(), ql.Actual360(True))

h = quotedTrade.impliedHazardRate(0,discountCurve,ql.Actual365Fixed(),
                                recovery,1e-10,
                                ql.CreditDefaultSwap.ISDA)

probabilityCurve.linkTo(ql.FlatHazardRate(0,ql.WeekendsOnly(),
                        ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(h)),
                        ql.Actual365Fixed()))

engine = ql.IsdaCdsEngine(probabilityCurve,recovery,discountCurve)
conventionalTrade = ql.CreditDefaultSwap(ql.Protection.Buyer,10000000,0,0.01,cdsSchedule,
                                            ql.Following,ql.Actual360(),True,True,trade_date,
                                            upfront_date, ql.FaceValueClaim(), ql.Actual360(True))
conventionalTrade.setPricingEngine(engine)

upfront = -conventionalTrade.notional() * conventionalTrade.fairUpfront()
```